# how do I bzr branch to an existing directory?

Tags: bazaar

I would like for my collaborators to be able to branch a project to an existing directory, since many already have the 'dir' directory which mirrors my own and I would prefer to minimize path lengths...

However, bzr won't let me do this:

```
mkdir dir
bzr branch ~/project/trunk dir
```

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mkdir dir
bzr branch ~/project/trunk dir --use-existing-dir
```